# How to build a kernel in Minix 3?

Tags: kernel, minix

Please someone explain complete step by step procedure of building of a kernel in Minix 3.

Thanks

Comment: What research have you done already?

Comment: I am working on OS project which requires this building a kernel in the first step. Can you please help me out.

Comment: What have you looked at already and why hasn't it worked? Does this page help? http://wiki.minix3.org/doku.php?id=developersguide:rebuildingsystem

Answer (score 0):

Go in */usr/src/releasetools* and type `make hdboot` in your command prompt. The first time you do this will take about half and hour or more depending on yor computer specification and how strong is your virtual machine. Every next recompile will be faster since some filed needed for installing will be laready created.
You can also write `make clean` which will clean your kernel if you had any errors or if some while doesn't exist anymore, and type `make hdboot` afterwards